# When try to insert data in mysql database it shows the query values are not specified

Tags: java, mysql, sql-insert

When I try to insert data into my MYSQL database by java. when the code run it shows the values that  I entered in text field are not specified.

**WHEN IT COMPILE THIS PRINT.**

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: INSERT INTO member_details(membership_number, date_join, name, id_number, date_of_birth, address, mobile_number, fixed_line, package, payment_due_date, package_amount)   VALUES(** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **);

```
Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
        date = jDateChooser1.getDate();
        DOB = sdf.format(date);
        
        Date date1 = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
        date1 = jDateChooserDOB.getDate();
        DOB = sdf1.format(date);
        
        String add_member = "INSERT INTO member_details(membership_number, date_join, name, id_number, date_of_birth, address, "
          + "mobile_number, fixed_line, package, payment_due_date, package_amount) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        
        try {
            Connection connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/ssfitness1?useSSL=false","root","Abc123");
            
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(add_member);
            System.out.println(preparedStatement);
            
            preparedStatement.setString(1, membershipnum.getText());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, DATE);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, name.getText());
            preparedStatement.setString(4, idnum.getText());
            preparedStatement.setString(5, DOB);
            preparedStatement.setString(6, address.getText());
            preparedStatement.setString(7, mobile.getText());
            preparedStatement.setString(8, fixedline.getText());
            preparedStatement.setString(9,String.valueOf(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()));
            preparedStatement.setString(10, duedate.getText());
            preparedStatement.setString(11, packageamount.getText());
            
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            
            System.out.println(preparedStatement);
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Member Added Successfully!!" );
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
```

Comment: Not sure that printing the `PreparedStatement` that way will print the final query. Maybe your query is actually good, and has been successfully executed.

Comment: Remove `;` from query inside `add_member`.

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej What do you mean? The semicolon is the correct statement terminator in SQL, as I recall.

Comment: By the way, you are using terrible date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: @BasilBourque because already have semicolon in this line `connection.prepareStatement(add_member);` so why we need to print semicolon in `add_member`.